# Statement in D&F about automorphisms acting on generators

Tags: field-theory

Is the following statement true in general?

If K is a field generated over F by some collection of elements, then any automorphism of K which fixes F is determined by what it does to the generators.

I am reading Dummit and Foote, and they write this not once but twice.  It seems to me like this isn't necessarily true unless the generators are algebraic over F.  Take, for example, $\mathbb{Q}(e)$, the field generated over $\mathbb{Q}$ by the transcendental e.  This set cannot be written as finite $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combinations for powers (positive and negative) of e since not every inverse is expressible this way. (I believe this follows from uniqueness of power series and such expressions as $\frac{1}{1+e}=\sum(-1)^ne^{-n-1}$).  So the statement does seem to have a chance of holding in this case.

Comment: When you write "$\mathbb{Q}(\mathrm{e})$", you seem to have confused (for a field, $F$) $F(\mathrm{e})$, a set of rational expressions, with $F[\mathrm{e}]$, the set of $F$-linear combinations of $1$ and $\mathrm{e}$.  In particular, $\frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}}$ is a rational expression in $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathrm{e}$, so is in $\mathbb{Q}(\mathrm{e})$.

Comment: If  $\sigma$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb Q(e)$, then $\sigma \left( \frac{1}{1 + e} \right) = \frac{1}{1 + \sigma(e)}$, so even in that example, the action of $\sigma$ is determined by how it acts on the generator $e$.

Comment: $\varphi : \mathbb{Q}(x) \to \mathbb{Q}(e), \varphi(x) = e$ is an isomorphism of fields. Bonus question : describe the endomorphisms and automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}(x)$

Comment: @Kenny Wong Why should an automorphism respect "division" like that?

Comment: So is the statement true in full generality?

Comment: @Eric Towers I know $\frac{1}{1+e}$ is in $\mathbb{Q}(e)$.  I don't think I understand your comment.

Comment: You write " This set cannot be written as finite Q-linear combinations for powers (positive and negative) of e".  Why would it need to?  This isn't what $\mathbb{Q}(\mathrm{e})$ **is**.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(e)$ is the field generated over $\mathbb{Q}$ by the element e, i.e., it contains $\mathbb{Q}$ and e and is closed under addition, multiplication and taking inverses.  Now, tell me, if you would, how an automorphism can be determined by its action on the generator e if the set $\mathbb{Q}(e)$ isn't made up of addition, multiplication and powers of e (i.e. the operations that homomorphisms respect).

Comment: If I change it to automorphisms of K that fix F does that clarify anything?

Comment: I am more interested in getting an answer to my question then finding out if my example is a good one.

Comment: Would you care to identify the kind of thing "$F$" is?

Comment: $\mathbb{F}(e)$ is the field of rational expressions in $\mathbb{F}$ and $e$, and automorphisms will preserve these.  I think the thing you're not seeing immediately is that $\sigma(\frac{1}{x}) =  \frac{1}{\sigma(x)}$.  But this must be true since $\sigma(x)\cdot\sigma(\frac{1}{x})=\sigma(1)=1$.

Comment: @Callus I mean I know this fact, it is why I said "positive and negative powers".  But I didn't think about fields generated by one element as the same thing as a field of rational polynomials.  So what if there are infinitely many generators?

Comment: The reason why I asked Kenny Wong that question is because I was not assuming that K had the form of rational functions; it was just a field closed under inverses in my mind.

Comment: @SihOASHoihd : In response to 'Why should an automorphism respect "division" like that?'  All field homomorphisms preserve all four field operations.  Consequently, any field homomorphism respects division like that.  Automorphisms are also homomorphisms...

Comment: @SihOASHoihd $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ means the field of rational expressions in $\alpha$ (if $\alpha$ is algebraic then $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)=\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$). The field of formal series, or the field of meromorphic functions are not of this form so we don't use the $K(\alpha)$ notation for them.

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand what you're missing.  And I think this is what Eric explained, too, in some very general way, but I'm going to be more hand-wavy.  To be more precise, I'd need to know what definition you're working with for a field extension generated by an element $e$, or more generally by a set $S$.

I think what's bothering you though is the following.  let $E$ be an extension of $F$ and let $S\subset E$ be a subset, then there is an extension field $F(S)$ which is defined to be the smallest subfield of $E$ that contains $S$.  To me, that's what $F(S)$ means.

Let $F\left< S\right>$ be the set of rational functions using symbols from $F$ and $S$.  Clearly this must be contained in $F(S)$.  Therefore if it is a field, it must be equal to $F(S)$, since it contains $F$ and $S$.  But showing it is a field is just a rote exercise in verifying the axioms of a field:  It has inverses, it has a $0$ and $1$, it is closed under addition and multiplication, etc.

Therefore $F(S)$ is precisely the set of rational expressions using symbols from $F$ and $S$.

Comment: (1/2) At the moment, I do not see why everyone seems so interested in notation.  To me (and D&F) F(a) means exactly what you say: its the smallest subfield containing F and a.

Comment: (2/2) Let me try and backtrack because I am pretty confused now.  I want to show that an automorphism is determined by its action on the generators.  When I posted the question I think what I was thinking was something like 'if the generators aren't algebraic, then I don't have a good description of what the field looks like, its not just linear combinations of powers of generators'.  But maybe you don't need to know what the field looks like for this to be true?  Perhaps you merely need the fact that inverses are mapped to inverses under a homomorphism?

Comment: I think you're right that you need to know that the elements of the field are finite expressions using the base field elements, the generator(s), and the field operations of addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division.  What I'm claiming in my answer is that this is the case.

Comment: Ah yeah I see now

Comment: Turns out you actually do in fact only need to know that the automorphisms preserve addition, multiplication, and inverses.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A,B$ be an algebraic objects of type $T$.  Let the algebraic operations $o_1, \dots, o_k$ for some positive integer $k$ be the operations of $T$.  Let the $T$-operations in $A$ be denoted $o_j^A$ and the $T$-operations in $B$ be denoted $o_j^B$ for $j = 1 \dots k$.  Suppose $A$ is generated as a $T$ by $a_1, \dots, a_n$ for some positive integer $n$.  A $T$-homomorphism, $\phi: A \rightarrow B$, is completely specified by $\varphi(a_i)$ for $i = 1 \dots n$.

**Comment**:  This isn't an algebraic fact, really.  It is a syntactic fact plus a very small amount of logic.  It's usually expressed by a variation of the phrase "extended by linearity".

**Proof**:  Any $a \in A$ is an expression, $x$, in the symbols $\{a_i \mid i=1\dots n\} \cup \{o_j^A \mid j = 1 \dots k\}$ since this is what "generated as a $T$" means.  Replacing in $x$ every "$a_i$" by "$\varphi(a_i)$" and every "$o_j^A$" by "$o_j^B$" yields an expression in $B$ for $\varphi(a)$.  Therefore, it is sufficient to specify $\varphi$ on the generators of $A$ and extend by linearity to the rest of the field.

We should verify that if $y$ is a different expression for $a$ that $\varphi$ yields an equivalent expression for $\varphi(a)$.  I.e., that the valuation equivalence is preserved by the substitution operation described above.  If $x$ and $y$ are different expressions for $a$, there is a proof of this fact. Applying the same replacement rules as above, we obtain a proof of equality of the replaced versions of $x$ and $y$ in $B$.  Consequently, the replacement operation above is well-defined with respect to choice of expression representative of $a$.

**Comment**:  There are more complicated algebraic objects for which we could permute the operations.  This doesn't happen for $T \in \{$ semigroup, quasigroup, loop, magma, monoid, group, ring, module, field, vector space, algebra $\}$, so I don't discuss this possibility.

**Example**:  In your example of $\mathbb{Q}(\mathrm{e})$, if I specify where $\mathrm{e}$ goes in my field map, $\varphi$, I have a completely specified map.  This is because by early lemmas, $\varphi(0_A) = 0_B$ and $\varphi(1_A) = 1_B$, which nails down the image of all of $\mathbb{Q}$ and then I've told you the image of $\mathrm{e}$ as well.  Consequently, we can apply $\varphi$ to any expression in $\mathbb{Q}(\mathrm{e})$ and get an expression in the image field.  Since $\varphi(\mathrm{e})$ is some element of the image field, so are all of its (integer) powers...

### Edit

I still read that you are conflating $\mathbb{Q}[\mathrm{e}]$, the *ring* operation with $\mathbb{Q}(\mathrm{e})$, the *field* operation.

$\mathbb{Q}[\mathrm{e}]$ is the set of all finite ring expressions (in the operations $+$, $-$, and $\times$, with arbitrary nesting) using elements of $\mathbb{Q} \cup \{\mathrm{e}\}$.  It is a lemma that each of these is equal to a finite $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combination of non-negative integer powers of $\mathrm{e}$.

$\mathbb{Q}(\mathrm{e})$ is the set of all finite field expressions (in the operations $+$, $-$, $\times$, and $\div$, with arbitrary nesting), excluding any occurrence of division by zero, using elements of $\mathbb{Q} \cup \{\mathrm{e}\}$.  It is a lemma that each of these is equal to a finite $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combination of non-negative integer powers of $\mathrm{e}$ divided by a nonzero finite $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combination of non-negative integer powers of $\mathrm{e}$.  Note that the multiplicative inverse of every nonzero such element is in this set.  Specifically, for $p,q$ nonzero finite $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combination of non-negative integer powers of $\mathrm{e}$, 
$$  \left( \frac{p}{q} \right)^{-1}  = \frac{q}{p}  \text{.}  $$

Comment: This is so unnecessarily convoluted; if you really understand the subject you would be able to give a simple explanation.  I simply want to know how  the action of the generators determine the automorphism when I don't know what the field extension looks like.  My guess is your knowledge of fields is really quite shallow.

Comment: @SihOASHoihd : Keep guessing.

Comment: "Would you care to identify the kind of thing "F" is?"

Comment: @SihOASHoihd : Yes.  You have used the symbol "$F$" in your Question without identifying it as a ring, field, algebra, et c.  You then seem to conflate $F(\mathrm{e})$ and $F[\mathrm{e}]$.

Comment: You thought I was talking about field extensions over algebras?

Comment: @SihOASHoihd : You were talking about "K is a field generated over F", where $F$ was never identified.  If $F$ were a ring, you would be talking about the field of fractions and it would have been sensible for you to talk about "set cannot be written as finite \mathbb{Q}-linear combinations for powers (positive and negative) of \mathrm{e}".  But not for you to use "$\mathbb{Q}(\mathrm{e})$" which is a field extension.